# VOIP push notification

Tags: ios, swift, voip

I want to play sound when my app kill in background mode. For this I am using VOIP notification. My method is call and sound play in foreground mode. But in background mode method call sound not fire. Here is my code snippet.

```
  func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload, forType type: String) {
    var a = payload.dictionaryPayload

      //  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(<#T##name: String?##String?#>, ofType: <#T##String?#>)

        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("demo", withExtension: "mp3")!

        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            guard let player = player else { return }

            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should configure AVAudioSession before you try to play sound? And configure the capabilities of your project (Target -> Capabilities -> Background Mode)

Comment: @AntonBelousov it working fine in foreground mode can we do seperate code for background mode

Answer (score 0):

Once you receive pushkit payload. You have to schedule local notification with sound file. Your sound file plays max for 30 seconds.

```
import UIKit
import PushKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,PKPushRegistryDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


        let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)

        self.PushKitRegistration()

        return true
    }

    //MARK: - PushKitRegistration

    func PushKitRegistration()
    {

        let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
        // Create a push registry object
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {

            let voipRegistry: PKPushRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)

            // Set the registry's delegate to self

            voipRegistry.delegate = self

            // Set the push type to VoIP

            voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushTypeVoIP]

        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }


    }


    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
        // Register VoIP push token (a property of PKPushCredentials) with server

        let hexString : String = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start: UnsafePointer(credentials.token.bytes),
            count: credentials.token.length).map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joinWithSeparator("")

        print(hexString)


    }


    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: PKPushPayload!, forType type: String!) {
        // Process the received push


    }

}
```

[Refer](https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification)

Comment: Does it worked for you? if yes then you can accept answer.